# Paper Size and Orientation in RDLC Report

Tags: barcode, rdlc, barcode-printing

I am printing Barcode Stickers. My problem is the size of the stickers. I am using [The "Citizen CLP-621" printer](http://www.citizen-systems.com/Product.aspx?id=25#1).

The problem is that I want to print stickers in portrait, but when I decrease the height in the rdlc report it converts the orientation to landscape.

How can I set the custom width (3.5 inch) and height (1.2 inch), but keep the portrait paper orientation?

Comment: have you gotten a solution to the issue?